# Why cant I get expert mode on Terraria?

Tags: terraria-console

So, me and my friend have been trying to figure out how to get expert mode on Terraria. We play the game on Xbox 360 and we saw something about expert mode and wanted to try it out but we can't figure out how to do it. Can someone please tell me how to get expert mode for Terraria on Xbox 360? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access expert mode because Terraria on Xbox 360 runs an "old-gen console" version. This includes PS3, Xbox 360 and Wii U consoles. [source](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Old-gen_console_version)

> Due to hardware requirement issues and memory constraints, this version cannot receive significant updates past the Desktop 1.2.4.1 equivalent.

Expert mode was released in desktop version 1.3.0.1